# Opening URLs from other apps for iPad only, and disabled on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Our universal app supports opening pdf files from other apps, but we only want to support it on iPad.

Is there a way to prevent an app from being listed in the Open In... menu when you long press on a pdf file if the device is iPhone?

Comment: Have two Info.plist files. One for the iPhone target and one for the iPad target, where the iPad plist handles PDF and the iPhone doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target specific device types by appending `~iphone`, `~ipad` or `~ipod` to the keys in `Info.plist`.  See [Creating Device-Specific Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW9) in the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

You can check on which device your app is running. For example
 `if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [self openPDF];
}`

Comment: The register for oping files is not at runtime, but a info.plist setting